# How to satisfy autolayout constraints on dynamically loading tables?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm using autolayout on two tables loaded into a view. I have constraints on both tables that sets a default height for them. After a table's data reloads
I reset its height to be the correct height (after all cells are loaded):

```
self.loadGames() { (boolValue) -> () in
    self.gamesTableView.reloadData()
    self.gamesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
    self.setupTableView(self.gamesTableView)
    self.gamesTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.gamesTableView.contentSize.height
}

self.loadNews() { (boolValue) -> () in
    self.newsTableView.reloadData()
    self.newsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150

    self.setupTableView(self.newsTableView)
    self.newsTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.newsTableView.contentSize.height
}

func setupTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I have another two constraints. One sets the distance between the tables, the other is a constraint between the second table and the bottom of the app screen. They're both 10px.

I'd like it so regardless of the size of the tables, the distance between them and the bottom of the app is always
satisfied. Right now that's not the case. I tried setting the priority but nothing happens. Both distances are larger.
is too:

[image: autolayout constraint issue]

How do I make sure the constraints are satisfied?

Comment: Reason for using 2 tables?

Comment: What is the case if the _true height_ of the `tableViews` don't extend the height of the `mainView`?

Comment: they are satisfying the required height but you can't see them because tableview has clear background and your content is less. assign background color to table view and try